# How do I prevent Win32 from setting the scroll range of the opposite bar to 100 when I call SetScrollInfo?

Tags: winapi

Check this out! This is for any Win32 application. I'm using MFC, but I don't think it's specific to that framework.

I've reproduced this on all kinds of windows, it does not appear to be related to style, extended style, or class style.

Here's what's happening: if a window has **no scrollbars**, and I set a range on just **one of the scroll orientations** (e.g. horizontal), then the **other orientation** (e.g. vertical) will now internally **have a range too**! I say "internally" because it will still not be visible, thank goodness, but the presence of the range is messing things up.

The most straightforward of demonstrations in pseudo-code:

```
GetScrollInfo(SB_HORZ); // min=0, max=0   --as expected
GetScrollInfo(SB_VERT); // min=0, max=0   --as expected
SetScrollInfo(SB_HORZ, 0, 5);
GetScrollInfo(SB_HORZ); // min=0, max=5   --as expected
GetScrollInfo(SB_VERT); // min=0, max=100 --what??
```

Try it yourself, it's crazy! What's even more crazy and frustrating, and how I ran into this in the first place, is that if you try to SetScrollPos() it will let you! So for example, if you called `SetScrollPos(SB_VERT, 3)` *before* the above, then `GetScrollPos(SB_VERT)` would return 0, but if I did it *after* the above, then it would return **3**! Again, notice that we're talking about SB_VERT which was never set to have a range at all!

It feels like I must be missing something, especially considering that the opposite scrollbar (the one with this inexplicable range max of 100, vertical in the above example) doesn't actually appear on screen.

(I've tried setting/getting the scroll info in many different combinations to try to diagnose this crazy problem, but it always comes back to the behavior that if you have NO scrollbars, and then you set just ONE, then the other one goes to 100.)

(And where'd that number (100) come from??)

**EDIT1:** Here's the actual code:

```
void func1(HWND hWnd)
{
    // this line logs: get(h) 0(1447)->0-0,0
    { SCROLLINFO si = { sizeof(SCROLLINFO), SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS }; SetLastError(0); int result = ::GetScrollInfo(hWnd, SB_HORZ, &si); TRACE(_T("get(h) %li(%li)->%li-%li,%li\n"), result, GetLastError(), si.nMin, si.nMax, si.nPage); }

    // this line logs: get(v) 0(1447)->0-0,0
    { SCROLLINFO si = { sizeof(SCROLLINFO), SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS }; SetLastError(0); int result = ::GetScrollInfo(hWnd, SB_VERT, &si); TRACE(_T("get(v) %li(%li)->%li-%li,%li\n"), result, GetLastError(), si.nMin, si.nMax, si.nPage); }

    // this line logs: set(h) 0(0)->0-5,1
    { SCROLLINFO si = { sizeof(SCROLLINFO), SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE, 0, 5, 1 }; SetLastError(0); int result = ::SetScrollInfo(hWnd, SB_HORZ, &si, FALSE); TRACE(_T("set(h) %li(%li)->%li-%li,%li\n"), result, GetLastError(), si.nMin, si.nMax, si.nPage); }

    // this line logs: get(h) 1(0)->0-5,1
    { SCROLLINFO si = { sizeof(SCROLLINFO), SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS }; SetLastError(0); int result = ::GetScrollInfo(hWnd, SB_HORZ, &si); TRACE(_T("get(h) %li(%li)->%li-%li,%li\n"), result, GetLastError(), si.nMin, si.nMax, si.nPage); }

    // this line logs: get(v) 1(0)->0-100,0
    { SCROLLINFO si = { sizeof(SCROLLINFO), SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS }; SetLastError(0); int result = ::GetScrollInfo(hWnd, SB_VERT, &si); TRACE(_T("get(v) %li(%li)->%li-%li,%li\n"), result, GetLastError(), si.nMin, si.nMax, si.nPage); }
}
```

**EDIT2:** To reiterate the question here: how do I work with this behavior and maintain modular code. Right now the only way I can find to work around it is with this kludgy function that wraps any call to SetScrollInfo() in a check+set of the opposite bar's state:

```
int MySetScrollInfo(HWND hWnd, int nBar, LPSCROLLINFO psi, BOOL bRedraw)
{
    int nOppositeBar = (nBar == SB_HORZ) ? SB_VERT : SB_HORZ;
    SCROLLINFO siOpposite = { sizeof(SCROLLINFO), SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS | SIF_TRACKPOS };
    ::GetScrollInfo(hWnd, nOppositeBar, &siOpposite);
    int ans = ::SetScrollInfo(hWnd, nBar, psi, bRedraw);
    if (siOpposite.nMin == siOpposite.nMax) {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        ::SetScrollInfo(hWnd, nOppositeBar, &siOpposite, bRedraw);
        SetLastError(dwErr);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

This cannot be right. What's the right way??

**EDIT3:** Blarg! That didn't work either, because it's not just when you set when the opposite one is nil, it's when you set one to anything (including nil) when BOTH were nil just prior. So what I ended up doing was overriding both GetScrollInfo and SetScrollInfo. Upon Set, I store a flag whether the caller is setting to nil, and then I check that flag on every Get. What a mess.

Comment: Show real code, not psuedo code.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to duplicate the claim that setting the range on one bar causes the range on the other to be initialized to 0-100.

It's probably a side effect for compatibility with apps that get the sequence wrong.

As for where the 100 comes from, the documentation for [GetScrollRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787587(v=vs.85).aspx) says:

> The default range for a standard scroll bar is 0 through 100.

"Standard" in this context means one of the non-client area scroll bars as opposed to a child scroll bar control.

Comment: There's a right sequence? I'm trying to make my code modular so that when something happens that causes the content to change only in its vertical extent I only call SetScrollInfo(SB_VERT). Are you saying I should always call twice, once for SB_VERT and once for SB_HORZ, regardless of which one I  really need to change? Which would mean reading the one I don't care about first, then setting the one I care about, then setting the one I don't care about. Yikes. That cannot be right. Maybe modular is not an option when it comes to scrollbars.

Comment: By "get the sequence wrong," I was refering to broken apps that initialize only one of the scroll bar ranges but then expect both of them to be set.  As long as you initialize both scroll bars (in either order), this shouldn't affect your program, even if your program treats them as independent.

Comment: Hrm, but it's not just the first time. It's any time you go from both orientations having a nil range to setting just one of them. Consider this sequence of getting and setting the range max: get(h); get(v); set(v, 5); set(h, 5); get(h); get(v); set(v, 0); set(h, 0); set(v, 5); get(h); get(v). The six _get_ calls in that sequence give the following six range max values: 0; 0; 5; 5; **100**; 5. What!? This is killing my modularity, because if the content gets set to both nil, and then content of one (e.g. vert) gets set to non-nil, all the sudden SetScrollPos(horz) is no longer constrained!

Comment: @bob:  Setting a scroll bar to a range of 0..0 seems pretty suspicious.  The range is a half-open range, so there's no legit position if the max equals the min.  So your options are (1) don't allow 0,0, (2) use scroll bar child controls instead of the "standard" ones, (3) save the settings for the "untouched" bar and then restore them after making a change to the other bar.

Comment: That's not a range of 0..0. Look at the output more carefully: The initial call to GetScrollInfo is *failing* with ERROR_NO_SCROLLBAR. Basically, scroll bars default to 0..100. If you ask before anything has been set, you might be told "You're asking too soon" but the moment you try to change anything, the default range of 0..100 is applied. So you should just behave as if the range had been 0..100 all along.